# NET MAUI - Keep keyboard focused on ListView update

Tags: c#, listview, maui, observablecollection, data-entry

I have a ListView with an ObservableCollection of Database Entries. When I update the Observable collection the focus of the Entry get lost and the keyboard disappears. Even when i set the focus afterwards manually the keyboard does not appear.

Thats my code.

Page.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:LoginManager.Models"
             x:Class="LoginManager.OverviewPage"
             BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightBackground}, Dark={StaticResource DarkBackground}}">

    <Grid Margin="10">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnSpacing="{OnPlatform WinUI=50, Default=0}" Margin="{OnPlatform WinUI='5,10,10,10', Default='0,-15,-10,-10'}">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border StrokeThickness="5"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20"
                    Padding="0,2.5,0,5"
                    Style="{StaticResource Border}"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">

                <Entry x:Name="SearchEntry"
                       Style="{StaticResource Entry}"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       FontSize="{OnPlatform WinUI='50', Default='35'}"
                       Placeholder="Suche"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       Margin="15,0,15,0"
                       IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                       TextChanged="SearchEntry_TextChanged"/>
            </Border>

            <ImageButton x:Name="SortByBtn"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}"
                         Source="sort_icon.png"
                         Aspect="AspectFit"
                         BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightAccent}, Dark={StaticResource DarkAccent}}"
                         Margin="0,5,0,5"
                         Padding="15"
                         HeightRequest="115"
                         WidthRequest="115"
                         HorizontalOptions="End"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                         Pressed="SortByBtn_Pressed"
                         Released="SortByBtn_Released"
                         Clicked="SortByBtn_Clicked"/>
            
        </Grid>

        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                Style="{StaticResource Border}"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightAccent}, Dark={StaticResource DarkAccent}}"
                StrokeThickness="2.5"
                StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20"
                Padding="2.5"
                Margin="{OnPlatform WinUI='0,7.5,0,7.5', Default='0,0,0,7.5'}"/>

        <ActivityIndicator Grid.Row="2"
                           IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           ZIndex="1"
                           Margin="100"
                           Color="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimary}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPrimary}}"/>

        <ListView x:Name="DatabaseEntriesListView"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Margin="20,0"
                  BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DbEntries}"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  ItemTapped="DatabaseEntriesListView_ItemTapped">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:DbEntry">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Text="Bearbeiten"/>
                            <MenuItem Text="Löschen"/>
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                        <Border Style="{StaticResource Border}"
                                Stroke="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimary}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPrimary}}"
                                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightSecondary}, Dark={StaticResource DarkSecondary}}"
                                StrokeThickness="5"
                                StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20"
                                Padding="20"
                                Margin="{OnPlatform WinUI='0,10,0,10', Default='0,2.5,0,2.5'}">
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource Label}"
                                   FontSize="{OnPlatform WinUI='35', Default='25'}"
                                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   MaxLines="1"
                                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
namespace LoginManager;

using LoginManager.Common;
using LoginManager.ViewModels;

public sealed partial class OverviewPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly OverviewViewModel _vm;

    public OverviewPage(OverviewViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _vm = vm;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        SortByBtn.Scale = 1;

        var loadedSuccessfully = await _vm.GetWholeDb(_vm.CurrentUser);

        if (!loadedSuccessfully)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Fehler", "Die Einträge konnten nicht geladen werden", "Okay");
            
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
        }
    }

    private async void SearchEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!SearchEntry.IsFocused) SearchEntry.Focus();

        await _vm.SearchEntriesBy(e.NewTextValue);

        if (!SearchEntry.IsFocused)
        {
            SearchEntry.Focus();
        }
    }

    private async void SortByBtn_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await SortByBtn.ScaleTo(0.95, 100, Easing.Linear);
        await SortByBtn.ScaleTo(1, 100, Easing.Linear);
    }

    private async void SortByBtn_Released(object sender, EventArgs e) => await SortByBtn.ScaleTo(1, 100, Easing.Linear);

    private async void SortByBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var chosen = await DisplayActionSheet("Sortieren nach...", null, "Abbrechen",
            "neueste zuerst", "älteste zuerst", "Alphabet aufsteigend", "Alphabet absteigend");

        var sortBy = chosen switch
        {
            "neueste zuerst" => SortBy.IdDESC,
            "älteste zuerst" => SortBy.IdASC,
            "Alphabet aufsteigend" => SortBy.NameASC,
            "Alphabet absteigend" => SortBy.NameDESC,
            _ => SortBy.None
        };

        await _vm.SortEntriesBy(sortBy);
    }

    private void DatabaseEntriesListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
namespace LoginManager.ViewModels;

using Common;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using LoginManager.Models;
using LoginManager.Services;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

[QueryProperty(nameof(CurrentUser), nameof(CurrentUser))]
public sealed partial class OverviewViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly IDatabase _db;

    public ObservableCollection<DbEntry> DbEntries { get; set; } = new();

    public OverviewViewModel(IDatabase db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    User currentUser;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(IsNotBusy))]
    bool isBusy;

    public bool IsNotBusy => !IsBusy;

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task<bool> GetWholeDb(User currentUser)
    {
        await LoadDb(currentUser);

        return DbEntries.Count is not 0;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public Task SortEntriesBy(SortBy sortBy)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        switch (sortBy)
        {
            case SortBy.NameASC:
                DbEntries.SortBy(x => x.Name);
                break;

            case SortBy.NameDESC:
                DbEntries.SortBy(x => x.Name, false);
                break;

            case SortBy.IdASC:
                DbEntries.SortBy(x => x.Id);
                break;

            case SortBy.IdDESC:
                DbEntries.SortBy(x => x.Id, false);
                break;
        }

        IsBusy = false;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public Task SearchEntriesBy(string? query)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query)) DbEntries.SortBy(x => x.Name.Count(x => query.Contains(x)));

        IsBusy = false;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task LoadDb(User currentUser)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        await foreach (var entry in _db.GetWholeAsync(currentUser))
        {
            DbEntries.Add(entry);
        }

        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

I tried setting a Delay for the TextChanged Event but it doesn't work either.
Also I don't want the Entry being unfocused and the keyboard going away at all.

Answer (score 0):

When the value of the Entry's IsEnabled property is false. The entry will be unfocusable and the keyboard will disappear.

But in your code, you set `public bool IsNotBusy => !IsBusy`. When the value of isBusy is true. The entry will be disabled. And when you set the `isBusy = true` again, the entry is enabled but it will not auto focus.

And for the android, if you call the `SearchEntry.Focus();` to make the entry focused, the keyboard will not appear unless the user click the entry. So you can use the following code to force the keyboard appear.

```
           SearchEntry.Focus();
#if ANDROID
            Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager inputManager = (Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager)Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
            inputManager.ToggleSoftInput(Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager.ShowForced, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);
#endif
```